# MS graph webhook subscription for /groups without membership changes included?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Currently, there is no way to create a subscription for change notifications that track changes to all /groups WITHOUT group membership changes. I know this functionality is available using delta queries with the $select parameter, but that is a pull operation rather than the automatic push notification that is available via webhook notifications/subscriptions.

Having this functionality can cut down on the number of notification messages received for groups where membership changes are NOT desired or wish to be tracked by this method - for which in that case, delta notifications could be substituted for that purpose as previously indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently change notifications for groups do not support $filter or $select odata query parameter to narrow down notifications. The solution in that case would be to use a combination of change notifications and Delta query where the change notification triggers requesting Delta changes which allow you in turn to determine the content of the change and whether it was "interesting" for your application.
If this is not a satisfying solution, you could look at [change notifications with resource data (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data), however this is not implemented for groups today so you'd have to request it on [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com). That or support for odata query parameters.

Comment: HI @baywet thank you for the reply.  But this does not solve my issue. Here's why.  The mere fact that the 'update' event is specified in the webhook request means all changes including membership changes will be included.  Imagine this: a user adds hundreds (if not thousands) of users to a group and because they are doing this via the API they already know the membership changes beforehand.  So all those superfluous events will be returned in the notifications even if only changes to the group properties are what is needed when they occur. Not efficient and creates unnecessary load. Smh.

Comment: Understand the pain here. The answer today: not possible, if you would like things to change, please ask on uservoice new features as this drives priorities, not stackoverflow.